# How do I set an id for an element xml in Java class?

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlt);
    TextView txtv=new TextView(this);//I want to set an Id for this element
    txtv.setText("My Text");
    layout.addView(txtv);
}
```

I want to set an id for txtv.
And..
How do I change the Other Attributes of this element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an ID by calling [setId](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int)).

```
public final static int MY_ID = 2;

TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setId(MY_ID);
```

You can set attributes using whatever the attribute name is. See [TextView documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).

```
tv.setText("Some text");
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response But it seems that setId receives an int ?

Comment: That's correct. IDs are always ints. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html